# C Linux Programming Book: Chapter Pipes

Tags: c, linux, pipe

I'm currently reading the book "[The Linux Programming Interface](http://man7.org/tlpi/code/online/book/pipes/simple_pipe.c.html)".
The example explaining pipes contains a piece of code which reads data from a pipe (inside the for loop, under the `case 0` statement):

```
numRead = read(pfd[0], buf, BUF_SIZE)
```

My question is: what is `pfd[0]`? I know it's a pipe file descriptor array, it was declared as `int pfd[2]`, so an array of integers of two elements. But what *is* the element `pfd[0]`? I cannot see it be initialized anywhere. If I print it then it's an integer (rather large) like 22302.

Comment: It's initialised here: `if (pipe(pfd) == -1) /* Create the pipe */`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `pipe` function has this signature:

```
int pipe(int pipefd[2]);
```

When you call it, it writes the two file descriptors into the array that you passed it.

The first file descriptor, `pipefd[0]` from the above statement, is for reading the output of the pipe.

The second file descriptor, `pipefd[1]` from the above statement, is for writing to the pipe.

Answer (score 0):

A UNIX pipe has two ends, a reading and a writing end, which both behave just like file descriptors. You read from `pfd[0]` and write to `pfd[1]`. You can close one end of the pipe, for example to signal that you are done writing data, and leave the other one open, for example to receive a response.